# Javascript: Add "Read More..." after a certain word

Tags: javascript

currently stuck with this issue. I have a huge text and want to display a "preview" of it with a "read more" button below. When clicking that button, the preview disappears and gets replaced by the rest of the text. This is for Job descriptions btw.

Currenly I am doing this character based:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var maxLength = 1507;
    var myStr = $(this).html();
    $(".jobdescription").each(function(){
        if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
            var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
            var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
            $(this).empty().html("");
            $(this).append('<span class="broiler-text">' + newStr+ '</span>');
            $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">Read full Job Description</a>');
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        }
    });
    $(".read-more").click(function(){
       $(".broiler-text").remove();
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
<style>
    .jobdescription .more-text {
        display: none!important;
    }
</style>
```

But this will not allow for ANY inconsistencies in characters used (can't go .text as it kills formating). So I would like to cut after a certain word (let's say "beetlejuice"). Sadly I am completely new to JS and was totally proud of piecing this script together in the first place before realizing the errors of my ways for this particular use case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with css defining it's width and

> overflow: hidden;
>         text-overflow: ellipsis;

```
.truncate {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 250px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    .truncate + a {
    display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
```

I leave you a snippet

```css
.truncate {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.truncate + a {
display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p><span class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi non interdum massa. Proin volutpat quam condimentum dui viverra varius. Sed tincidunt lacus arcu. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</span><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
```

Also there is a library that makes truncate for you, you need to specify selector and lines => cramp.js https://github.com/curalate/Cramp.js/tree/master

```
**//Single line $cramp(myHeader, {cramp: 1});

//Multi-line $cramp(myHeader, {cramp: 3});

//Auto-cramp based on available height $cramp(myParagraph, {cramp: 'auto'});

//Auto-cramp based on a fixed element height $cramp(myParagraph, {cramp: '35px'});**
```

Comment: Good idea for the future but won't work for a Job Description with "Preview" with varying length. Hence why I need it to cut after a certain keyword which will always stay the same. Best would be if the keyword itself is then cut completely. Edit: Also this .jobdescription element is fed by another software. Ican't directly influence it. The whole thing sits in a wordpress like builder that just allows me adjustments with css and javascript.